# PHP GD and Special Characters

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, gd

I created an script to generate images from text. I'm using a TTF Font, "Bebas Neue" and i have a problem with special characters. For example:

```
In html this text is fine ♥ 

In the image this text is not fine, the heart view as a rectangule or another wrong symbol ♥
```

The same problem ocurred with others symbols: ☼ ♪ ♂ ♥

I add this header to the start of the page:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Thanks!

**Sorry, I forgot to tell you that with the Arial font, the symbols look good**

Comment: So your chosen font does not contain those symbols...!

Comment: But, why in html this chars view normally?

Comment: In the same font? Because the browser has pretty elaborate fallback mechanisms if a glyph does not exist in a font. gd's font handling is a lot more simplistic.

Comment: Looks like a character-map issue. The font is probably a symbolic font with a Unicode mapping.